# Saving XLSX workbooks as multiple CSV files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, openpyxl

Trying to save Excel files with multiple sheets as corresponding CSV files.
I tried the following method:

```
import xlrd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import pathlib
import shutil
import pandas as pd

def strip_xlsx(inputdir, file_name, targetdir):
    wb = load_workbook(inputdir)
    sheets = wb.sheetnames
    for s in sheets:
        temp_df = pd.read_excel(inputdir, sheet_name=s)
        temp_df.to_csv(targetdir + "/" + file_name.strip(".xlsx") + "_" + s + ".csv", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Where `inputdir` is an absolute path to a the Excel file (say: "/Users/me/test/t.xlsx"), file_name is just the name of the file ("t.xlsx") and target_dir is a path to which I wish to save the csv files.

The methods works well, thought super slow. I'm a newbie to Python and feel like I implemented the method in a very inefficient way.

Would appreciate tips from the masters.

Comment: Use `read_only=True` when loading the workbooks.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You may have better luck if you keep everything in pandas. I see you are using openpyxl to get the sheet names, you can do this in pandas. As for speed, you'll just have to see:</s>

EDIT:

As Charlie (the person who probably knows the most about openpyxl on the planet) pointed out, using just openpyxl will be faster. In this case about 25% faster (9.29 ms -> 6.87 ms for my two-sheet test):

```py
from os import path, mkdir
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv

def xlsx_to_multi_csv(xlsx_path: str, out_dir: str = '.') -> None:
    """Write each sheet of an Excel file to a csv
    """
    # make the out directory if it does not exist (this is not EAFP)
    if not path.exists(out_dir):
        mkdir(out_dir)
    # set the prefix
    prefix = path.splitext(xlsx_path)[0]
    # load the workbook
    wb = load_workbook(xlsx_path, read_only=True)
    for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
        # generate the out path
        out_path = path.join(out_dir, f'{prefix}_{sheet_name}.csv')
        # open that file
        with open(out_path, 'w', newline='') as file:
            # create the writer
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            # get the sheet
            sheet = wb[sheet_name]
            for row in sheet.rows:
                # write each row to the csv
                writer.writerow([cell.value for cell in row])

xlsx_to_multi_csv('data.xlsx')
```

Comment: openpyxl will let you stream XLSX to CSV. As both are row-oriented file formats, this will always be faster than going through a dataframe.

Comment: @CharlieClark no kidding, 25% faster! I'll update the answer. I don't like the amount of reliance people have on pandas nowadays.

Comment: Guys, this works great. Thanks so much! One thing - I had to add a third variable "file_name" so I can save the sheets as ```file_name+"_"+f'{sheet_name}.csv'```
It feels like a walk-around though...
Is there a way to extract from a full path just the name of the file?

Comment: @GavrielGoidel of course! see the updated `prefix = path.splitext(xlsx_path)[0]` and `f'{prefix}_{sheet_name}.csv'` it would also be possible to set the prefix manually with an argument

Comment: Pandas is great for the T in ETL, but if you don't need to transform anything, then you can cut it out. To be fair to the developers, they've done an excellent job to make it the goto tool. But, with Python's focus on orthogonality, it's usally also not that difficult to build your own pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify a path to save the csv's to, and iterate through a dictionary created by pandas to save the frames to the directory.

```
csv_path = '\path\to\dir'
for name,df in pd.read_excel('xl_path',sheet_name=None).items():
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(csv_path,name)
```